# Rails paperclip content type validation with client_side_validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip for images. I want to make sure that only images files(jpeg/png) are uploaded.
Here is my paperclip validation rule.

```
validates_attachment :photo, :presence => { :message => "is required" }, :content_type => { :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'], :message => "Invalid content type" }
```

The validation works and record is not saved if user uploads a non-image file. But the error message gets stored in @news.errors.messages[:**photo_content_type**] instead of @news.errors.messages[:**photo**]

I am using client-side-validations gem to display error messages. Since invalid content type message is attached to :**photo_content_type**, it is not displayed inline.

Right now I am displaying the message as follows:

```
<% if @news.errors.messages[:photo_content_type] %>
    <div class="field_with_errors">
        <%= f.file_field :photo %>
        <label for="" class="validation-error-message">
            <%= @news.errors.messages[:photo_content_type][0] %>
        </label>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way so that If user uploads a non image file, the message gets added to @news.errors.messages[:photo]

**Update**
I added after validation callback:

```
after_validation :join_img_errors

def join_img_errors
  if errors.messages.has_key?(:photo_content_type)
    errors.messages[:photo] = errors.messages[:photo_content_type]
  end
end
```

This way, I don't have to modify view code. But I still have to add the callback to all the models that use paperclip.